# Accessing file geodatabase (.gdb) rasters with GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, file-geodatabase

I'm working on a tool that converts raster layers to arrays for processing with NumPy, and ideally I would like to be able to work with rasters that come packaged in a .gdb without exporting them all (especially if this requires engaging ArcGIS or ArcPy).

Is this possible with the OpenFileGDB driver?

From what I can tell this driver seems to treat raster layers the same as vector layers, which gives you access to some data about the layer but doesn't give you the ReadAsArray functionality.

Comment: From http://erouault.blogspot.fi/2014/01/ogr-openfilegdb-driver.html: `I've encountered a few raster File Geodatabase datasets
(apparently tiled), and a quick inspection of the tables makes me believe
that a raster driver would be doable.` Thus, probably doable but not done.

Comment: @user30184 are you aware of the evolution related to this question. Can gdal 2 read rasters in gdb ?

Comment: I'm not aware of it, but would be interested to find out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading and writing file geodatabase rasters is not supported by the File Geodatabase API as of July 2015. According to this 2010 Esri blog [File Geodatabase API details](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3):

> Rasters (Raster Dataset, Raster Catalog, Mosaic Datasets and Raster
>   Attributes) are not supported with the initial release of the File
>   Geodatabase API.

Additionally, according to an Esri Staff member on a [Geonet discussion (June 2015)](https://geonet.esri.com/community/developers/gis-developers/file-geodatabase-api):

> Currently we do not have any plans on supported access to raster data
>   via the File Geodatabase API. If you feel this is needed, please add
>   it to the Esri Ideas site and it will be considered for a…

Answer (score 2):

The ability to read Raster layers from File Geodatabases has now been added to GDAL v3.7 (https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/7389)

Feature also now in QGIS - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/52214

Comment: And gdal 3.7 has now been released.

Answer (score 1):

Raster data stored in File Geodatabases is currently not supported by GDAL/QGIS.
There is work being done by Nyall Dawson and North Road along with members of the GDAL development community to hopefully bring this feature to light in the upcoming time.

Watch this page for news regarding the development of the raster driver:
https://north-road.com/blog/

Comment: Theres an issue at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/173

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/456483/138547