# How to read file geodatabase with Binary field in R?

Tags: r, convert, layer-file

Short version: how can I get into R the dataset available [at this link](http://databasin.org/datasets/96a4bf19c331413b9c5acc783adcfabc#)?  (you need to log in to download, but registration is free)

The dataset that is downloadable at that link expands to a directory; as pointed out in the comments, this is an ESRI file geodatabase, and the important stuff is in a subdirectory. The format was [reverse engineered](http://erouault.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/filegdb-format-reverse-engineered.html) and is [readable by GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html):

```
$ ogrinfo eschscholzia_minutiflora_twisselmannii/data/v93/tempgdb.gdb
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `eschscholzia_minutiflora_twisselmannii/data/v93/tempgdb.gdb'
  using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
1: Eschscholzia_minutiflora_ssp_twisselmannii (Multi Polygon)
```

However, reading this into R results in:

> x <-readOGR('eschscholzia_minutiflora_twisselmannii/data/v93/tempgdb.gdb', 
>        'Eschscholzia_minutiflora_ssp_twisselmannii')

```
Error in readOGR("eschscholzia_minutiflora_twisselmannii/data/v93/tempgdb.gdb",  :
Unsupported field type: Binary
```

Another tack, using `ogr2ogr`, produces a shapefile:

```
$ ogr2ogr --mapFieldType Binary=Integer test_output eschscholzia_minutiflora_twisselmannii/data/v93/tempgdb.gdb/
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FOOTPRINT_Length' to 'FOOTPRINT_'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'FOOTPRINT_Area' to 'FOOTPRIN_1'
Warning 1: Value 121687920 of field FOOTPRINT_ of feature 0 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width
Warning 1: Value 925496867120400 of field FOOTPRIN_1 of feature 0 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width
```

but the resulting shapefile doesn't seem to have the information in it.  Or, maybe I don't know the right way to read it into R?

Comment: You can read it directly into R with rgdal::readOGR, try "x <- readOGR('eschscholzia_minutiflora_twisselmannii/data/v93/tempgdb.gdb', 'Eschscholzia_minutiflora_ssp_twisselmannii')"  but no idea about the .lyr file specifically. See ?ogrListLayers to discover information about the layer/s in the data set.

Comment: That doesn't work (see revised post): maybe this has to do with the new `mapFieldType` option?

Comment: The main file you're downloading is an Esri File Geodatabase, so you could check the R documentation to see whether they explain how to work with this (the *.lyr layer file is used within Esri software to provide ready-made symbols, labels, etc and doesn't contain any actual content)

Comment: This may also help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151622/3112

Comment: @stephen-lead Thanks.  It seems the problem is the `Binary` format of the fields?

Comment: Try "drop_unsupported_fields=TRUE" see ?readOGR

Comment: Scratch that, I believe your data is a raster. R can't read the geodatabase raster (neither can GDAL). Get them to provide a useable format is the only option I'm afraid. When you read it as vector (or convert to shapefile) I think you just get the bounding box polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those data are rasters, and sadly (as of December 2015) it seems there's **no way** to read file geodatabase rasters with open source tools. The nice folk(s) who reverse-engineered the format [haven't done rasters](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2014/01/ogr-openfilegdb-driver.html), and as described in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129423/how-to-access-file-geodatabase-gdb-rasters-with-gdal), ESRI isn't helping.  =(