# How to convert a raster to .bgd (ESRI binary raster)

Tags: raster, gdal, raster-conversion

I need to use a `.bgd` (ESRI binary raster) because it seems to be the only raster format accepted out of the box in the [DotSpatial .NET library](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial).

My source files are mainly `.rrd`/`.adf`/`.tif` files. So I instead of trying to add the gdal extension to my DotSpatial code (I tried and I failed), I am trying to convert a raster to `.bgd`.

My guess was that `ogr2ogr` should be able to do it, using a command line similar to:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/Temp/Shps C:/Temp/test.gdb parcel citybnd
```

But when I look into the [GDAL raster formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) I don't see anything similar to `.bgd` that can help me figure out which command line I should use for this `.bgd` conversion.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `.gdb` aka. ESRI File GeoDataBase?

Comment: @Kersten Looking at DotSpatial's source code, it seems to be `.bgd`, not `.gdb`: https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/blob/master/Source/DotSpatial.Data/BinaryRasterProvider.cs

Comment: I suppose that .bgd is a native DotSpatial format (not ESRI binary raster). GDAL does not have a driver for that. I suggest to retry adding the GDAL extension.

Comment: @user30184 That would explain why I don't see any info about this `.bgd` type extension... In that case, as you say, I would have to dig deeper into how to make DotSpatial accept other raster formats through the GDAL extension.

Comment: Sources to binary raster reader https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/DotSpatial.Data/1.0.1-echo/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0,Profile%3DClient/DotSpatial.Data/DotSpatial.Data/BgdRaster.cs?ImageName=DotSpatial.Data with header `The Initial Developer of this Original Code is Ted Dunsford. Created 7/6/2009 10:14:34 AM`

Comment: https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue

Comment: Esri supports three generic binary formats for band sequential  (`.bsq`), band interleaved by line (`.bil`), and band interleaved by pixel (`.bip`). These are not, of course, *Esri* formats, just a naming and metadata convention agreed upon by the GIS vendors of the day, and documented by Esri. I have never heard of a `.bgd` extension in 28 years with Esri.

Comment: @Vince I got the bgd-ESRI connection from [this page](https://www.file-extensions.org/bgd-file-extension), which of course doesn't look very trustworthy ... but it's the only info I could find about "bgd" outside `DotSpatial`. The most likely hypothesis seems to be the one from user30184, which is that `.bgd` is a native DotSpatial format. DotSpatial is the underlying library of the new MapWindow version (v6 I think).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that GDAL does not support what you write as being gdb. I don't know very much ESRI but could not find it either on their [website](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm).

Aren't you looking for geodatabase rasters (.gdb)? In such case, it's indeed not support as GDAL only supports vectors in ESRI geodatabases. See [Accessing file geodatabase (.gdb) rasters with GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129423)

I would recommend not using a library which forces you to use a proprietary format for rasters.

What about using the [CSharp bindings](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) of GDAL?

Or maybe if you need a higher level API (display and render maps) using QGIS python API? You might find this example of a custom QGIS python application useful: [Roam application](https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam)

Comment: It is a bit confusing because the letters are the same but in different order, but looking at DotSpatial's source code I'd say that [the accepted format is `.bgd` (not `.gdb`)](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/blob/master/Source/DotSpatial.Data/BinaryRasterProvider.cs). About CSharp GDAL bindings, DotSpatial asks for a [very specific way to link to GDAL](https://mudnug.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/how-to-support-loading-extensions-in-dotspatial/), which looks difficult to maintain and I would like to avoid. Maybe I'll have to giving up on c# and embracing python and QGIS, we'll see.Thanks!